# How to hide specific buttons in Webview while rendering HTML in react native

Tags: html, react-native, iframe, react-native-webview

I am showing embedded iframe document in my application, what I am trying to do is hiding menu button from top bar in Webview of this embedded iframe. I am using [DocumentCloud](https://www.documentcloud.org) platform for storing and retrieving the documents, DocumentCloud gives me the link of my document and I add that my html and rendering it using [react-native-webview](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-webview). [This](https://www.documentcloud.org/documents/282753-lefler-thesis.js) is my iframe tag link, you can open it browser. I did tried achieving this using changing fields/options in iframe src url which is probably best solution for it, but I couldn't find any option to turn that thing off in document cloud documentation. I am getting this results.

[image: Currently it is looking like this]

I want to hide the the menu icon shown in top bar in above image.

iFrame looks like this

```
 <iframe loading="lazy" src="https://www.documentcloud.org/documents/282753-lefler-thesis.js" width="700" height="800" sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin allow-popups allow-forms allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

This is how I am rendering Webview.

```
<WebView
          scrollEnabled={false}
          onMessage={callback}
          style={styles.container}
          containerStyle={styles.viewContainer}
          source={{
            html: htmlRender(
              iframe
            ),
          }}

        />
```

htmlRender method is wrapping iframe within in html and doing some styling and reporting the height and width of iframe.

Comment: You can try to use injectJavaScript method, and hide that buttons by javascript

Comment: Yeah I trying to do that, I am already calculating height of the iframe through injected javascript but still not able to detect that button and hide it through that.

Answer (score 0):

You can `injectJavaScript` and query these buttons with 2 selectors:

```js
document.querySelector('.hamburger')
```

returns `div` with `svg`

```js
document.querySelector('.fullscreen')
```

returns `span` with `svg`

Hiding is something like:

```js
document.querySelector('.hamburger').style.display = "none";
```

Comment: Yeah I have tried that but haven't got the expected results. This is how my html content is looking

Comment: why do you need iframe?

Comment: I am rendering different kind of iframes on different screen, I have made a component of iframe and using that, this document is a figure, my question is that how can I pick this embedded figure class from this whole html content and hide hamburger and fullscreen icon from that figure.

Comment: try to use this selector `document.querySelector('body .hamburger')`

Comment: No didn't work.

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <style>
        body {
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
        }
      </style>
      <title>IFrame</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      ${iFrameTag}
      <script>
        function updateDesign() {
          document.querySelector('body .hamburger')style.display = "none";
        }

        window.onload = function() {
            updateDesign();
        };
      </script>
    </body>
  </html>`